# How do you use different class names in component depending on route?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 pages that use the same Search component. I'd like the search component to look different depending on what page it's on. I currently have class .btn I want to use on the Home page but I don't know how to switch to another class if it's on the GetWordContainer page. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

**Part of App.js where the routes for both pages are**

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={ routeProps => 
      <Home 
        {...routeProps} />} 
      />
    <Route exact path="/definition/:word" render={routeProps => 
      <GetWordContainer 
        {...routeProps} />} 
      />
  </Switch>
```

**Part of search component - I currently have one style I want to use on the Home page**

class Search extends Component {

```
render (){
  return (
    <div>
      <button className={styles['btn']} type="submit">search</button>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default Search;
```

**Search css - this is the one style I have, which I want to use for the Home page**

```
.btn{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    /* display:block; */
    border-radius:50px 50px 50px 50px;
    width:200px;
    height:60px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:700;
    font-family:segoe ui light;
    background-color:#CDA177;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write two or more styles in search bar css file. Then you could design your component in order to accept a new prop (like *theme*) in order to match in the right way your predefined style.

```
<Search theme={'style-home'} />

<Search theme={'style-counter'} />
```

In your component:

```
<button className={styles[this.props.theme]} type="submit">search</button>
```

In this way you will develop a reusable component which won't depend to your application specific pages (getWordContaimer, etc)

Comment: Awesome, works great. Thanks for the quick solution!